# Laptop freezes just before training of the network starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

My tensorflow codes were running fine until a week ago but now my laptop just freezes before training of the neural net. My other regular python code are running fine even now.

I don't think it's a memory issue as I took care of that. The below is the last line I see in the console

> OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY:pid 18364 tid 640 thread 31 bound to OS proc set 7

After this, the laptop just freezes.

Device info:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM)i7-7700HQ CPU@2.80Hz
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GDDRS @3.0 GB (192-bit)
930GB HD (438 GB available)
12GB RAM (8.4 GB available)
```

Other info:

```
IDE: Jetbrains PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.1
Python 3.7
Tensorflow version : 1.15.0
```

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible sample. Also, what do you mean by freezing? What operating system are you running? Basically, we need more information.

Comment: Most probably, it's running out of memory